# How to import the constant that is assigned a function result in javascript

Tags: javascript

what is the correct way to do this?

I have a function in file1 like this.

```
const func = () => 5;

export const x = func();
```

In a different file I am importing this function like below in file2

```
import {x} from file1;

const component = () => {
  const y = x;
}
```

Now I don't want to run the func function everytime so is this okay to do like above or should I convert it into -

```
export const x = (() => 5)();
```

Comment: There is no difference. In both cases you're only evaluating the function once. But why have a function at all, why not just `export const x = 5`

Comment: the last one is only one line of code

Answer (score 4):

The file is being executed only once, no matter how many times you `import` it.

Writing this:

```
const func = () => 5;

export const x = func();
```

Is strictly equivalent to this:

```
export const x = (() => 5)();
```

For a consumer point of view, and also performance point of view.

Answer (score 2):

Just try this, it will be enough for not to run automatically function.

In file1:

```
export const x = () => 5
```

In file2:

```
import { x } from file1;

const component = () => {
  const y = x();
}
```